# What's the equivalent in Linux for WaitForMultipleObjectsEx?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I'm rewriting a Windows-based signal processing engine which I developed ten years ago.  I now want it to run under both Windows and Linux.

Ideally I want to use a portable C++ library to help with this, but I'm also prepared to implement the code myself if that's less work -- i.e. to map Windows system calls to Linux system calls.   I'm not a Linux expert though.

I'm having difficulty removing the dependency on the Windows Object model in a central routine: The task scheduler, which uses WaitForMultipleObjectsEx to implement the [proactor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) design pattern:

```
for (;;) {
    while (WAIT_IO_COMPLETION == (evt_idx = ::WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(n_handles, events+current_eventlist_idx, FALSE, INFINITE, TRUE)))
                ;
    evt_id = evt_idx+current_eventlist_idx-WAIT_OBJECT_0;
    if (evt_id >= n_handles)
        evt_id -= n_handles;

    if (evt_id == 0) // 0 == terminate event
        break;
    // bump round-robin eventlist pointer
    if (++current_eventlist_idx == n_handles)
        current_eventlist_idx = 0;

    // make zero indexed
    --evt_id;
    // execute the processor chain
    (*schedules[evt_id].chain())();

}
```

The above does round-robin polling of Windows events. 
These events might be:

- Semaphores explicitly raised in user code (i.e. my code);
- Events explicitly set in user code (e.g. a device becomes connected);

Windows IO completion events which are raised by IO reads/writes and by queuing user work items via  [QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684957(v=vs.85).aspx) do **not** break the `while` loop in the code above: They're handled by Windows IO completion ports:  These events cause the  `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` call to return, but not to break the `while` loop - they allow the I/O completion callbacks to run, after which the task scheduler immediately starts another  `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` call, and continues to wait for any user-code triggered events.

The thing to note about `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` is that it allows a very heterogenous set of events to all be waited on at the same time, both from the system, and from user code.

The closest I've found in Linux to it is to use a combination of [poll(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) and [eventfd(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/eventfd) - Is this a good way to go?

[Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core.html), which I've used in other applications, looks like it can do what I want, but I'm struggling to map the functionality in the above routine to use it.   Am I missing something there?

Are there other portable libraries I should be considering?

Comment: I personally have used the eventfd+poll combination you mentioned and wrapped in under and abstract class, that does this on posix and WaitForMultipleObjects on Windows. Worked fine.